# laravel 4: linkRoute unwanted question mark

Tags: php, laravel-4

Recently, I've encountered with a weird issue. I'm using `laravel-4`.
I use blow code to create links in view that refer to route.

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute($route, $menuLink,'' ,array($status)) }}
```

As you know:

- `$route` is the route name.
- `$menuLink` is the text of the link.
- `$status` is an attribute which contains "selected" string or "" (null).

The problem is, in every link which I create like this there is a question mark `?` at the end of url. For instance:
`http://domain.dev/cp/contents?`. 
By the way, when I change the `linkRoute` and remove two last parameters, the question mark disappear:

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute($route, $menuLink) }}
```

Do you have any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `null` not `''`.

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute($route, $menuLink, null ,array($status)) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `{{ HTML::linkRoute($route, $menuLink, array(), array($status)) }}` or, even better if it accepts it, `{{ HTML::linkRoute($route, $menuLink, null, array($status)) }}`.